# Is it possible to invoke a function with a unaryPlus in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dsl, visitor-pattern, builder-pattern

This is a followup question on another question I asked yesterday.

[How can I build a nested list using builder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079118/how-can-i-build-a-nested-list-using-builder-pattern)

Credit to: [Pelocho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5132804/pelocho) for giving nice answer.

I used [this Tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) to do a type safe graphQL query builder:

**What I want to do now is to simplify what I made**
And I know that kotlin must have some nice features to do that.

Right now I have to invoke functions when I want to add an entity to my query:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    events{
        title() // I don't like to do () when it is an edge case
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is posible to do something different, and more simple, like:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    events{
        title // this is much nicer
    }
}
```

But if it is not possible then it is ok just to reduce the amount of characters with an **operator overloading** like eg. `unaryPlus`

```kotlin
fun main() {
    events{
        +title // this is also nicer
    }
}
```

My code that I have now has a class called `Query` where I put the method:

```kotlin
    operator fun Query.unaryPlus() {
        visitEntity(this,{})
    }
```

But it does not seem to work for me.

All my code is here.

```kotlin
interface Element {
    fun render(builder: StringBuilder, indent: String)
}

@DslMarker //Domain Specific Language
annotation class GraphQLMarker


@GraphQLMarker
abstract class Query(val name: String) : Element {
    val children = arrayListOf<Element>()
    protected fun <T : Element> visitEntity(entity: T, visit: T.() -> Unit = {}): T {
        entity.visit()
        children.add(entity)
        return entity
    }

    override fun render(builder: StringBuilder, indent: String) {
        builder.append("$indent$name")
        if (children.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.append("{\n")
            for (c in children) {
                c.render(builder, "$indent  ")
            }
            builder.append("$indent}")
        }
        builder.append("\n")
    }

    operator fun Query.unaryPlus() {
        visitEntity(this,{})
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        render(builder, "")
        return builder.toString()
    }
}
```

Then I created the classes relevant to my case

```kotlin
class Filter private constructor(val filters: MutableMap<FilterType, Any>) {
    class Builder {
        private val filters = mutableMapOf<FilterType, Any>()
        fun filters(key: FilterType, value: Any) = apply {
            this.filters[key] = value
        }

        fun build(): Filter {
            return Filter(filters)
        }
    }
}

class EVENTS(private val filter: Filter) : Query("events") {
    override fun render(builder: StringBuilder, indent: String) {
        builder.append("{$name")
        if (filter.filters.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.append("(" + filter.filters.map {
                if (it.value is Int || it.value is Long) {
                    it.key.str + ":" + it.value + ","
                } else {
                    it.key.str + ":\"" + it.value + "\","
                }
            }.joinToString(" ").dropLast(1) + ")")
        }
        if (children.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.append("{\n")
            for (c in children) {
                c.render(builder, "$indent  ")
            }
            builder.append("$indent}")
        }
        builder.append("\n}")
    }

    fun title() = visitEntity(TITLE())
    fun genre() = visitEntity(GENRE())
    fun image() = visitEntity(IMAGE())
    fun link() = visitEntity(LINK())
    fun other() = visitEntity(OTHER())
    fun price() = visitEntity(PRICE())
    fun text() = visitEntity(TEXT())
    fun tickets() = visitEntity(TICKETS())
    fun time() = visitEntity(TIME())
    fun location(visit: LOCATION.() -> Unit) = visitEntity(LOCATION(), visit)
}

class TITLE : Query("title")
class GENRE : Query("genre")
class IMAGE : Query("image")
class LINK : Query("link")
class OTHER : Query("other")
class PRICE : Query("price")
class TEXT : Query("text")
class TICKETS : Query("tickets")
class TIME : Query("time")
class LOCATION : Query("location") {
    fun area() = visitEntity(AREA())
    fun place() = visitEntity(PLACE())
    fun address(visit: ADDRESS.() -> Unit) = visitEntity(ADDRESS(), visit)
    fun coordinates(visit: COORDINATES.() -> Unit) = visitEntity(COORDINATES(), visit)
}

class AREA : Query("area")
class PLACE : Query("place")
class ADDRESS : Query("address") {
    fun city() = visitEntity(CITY())
    fun street() = visitEntity(STREET())
    fun no() = visitEntity(NO())
    fun state() = visitEntity(STATE())
    fun zip() = visitEntity(ZIP())
}

class CITY : Query("city")
class STREET : Query("street")
class NO : Query("no")
class STATE : Query("state")
class ZIP : Query("zip")
class COORDINATES : Query("coordinates") {
    fun longitude() = visitEntity(LONGITUDE())
    fun latitude() = visitEntity(LATITUDE())
}

class LONGITUDE : Query("longitude")
class LATITUDE : Query("latitude")

enum class FilterType(val str: String) {
    PLACE("place"),
    PRICELT("priceLT"),
    PRICEGT("priceGT"),
    TIMELT("timestampLT"),
    TIMEGT("timestampGT"),
    AREA("area"),
    TITLE("title"),
    GENRE("genre")
}
```

Some of the classes are **edgecases** and will not nest themself further down. So I was thinking if it is possible to simplify that a bit. And if I can use a `unaryPlus` to invoke them when I call them from the `main()` function, so I dont have to write `{}` after very single edgecase, when they dont have nesting anywaits

```kotlin
fun main(){
    events(filter) {
        title()
        genre()
        image()
        link()
        tickets()
        other()
        price()
        text()
        time()
        location {
            area()
            place()
            address {
                city()
                street()
                no()
                state()
                zip()
            }
            coordinates {
                longitude()
                latitude()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I build a nested list using builder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079118/how-can-i-build-a-nested-list-using-builder-pattern)

Comment: :D its my own question from yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `unaryPlus` for whatever you want

Check the [Operator overloading documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)

Here you have a working example:

```
fun main() {
    val events = events {
        +title
        +genre
    }

    println(events.render())
}

interface Element {
    fun render() : String
}

@DslMarker //Domain Specific Language
annotation class GraphQLMarker

@GraphQLMarker
fun events(init: EventBody.() -> Unit): Element {
    val events = EventBody()
    events.init()
    return events
}


class EventBody: Element {
    override fun render() =
        "events:${elements.joinToString { it.render() }}"

    private val elements = mutableListOf<Element>()

    operator fun Element.unaryPlus() = elements.add(this)
}

@GraphQLMarker
object title: Element {
    override fun render() = "title"
}

@GraphQLMarker
object genre: Element {
    override fun render() = "genre"
}
```

which outputs

```
events:title, genre
```

Comment: Thank you, but the functions still ask for parentheses for invocation. I updated my question for clarity.

Comment: You'll always need `()` for invoking a function (or `{}` if the last argument is a lambda). So don't do it, don't invoke a function. Define your stuff as simple `object`s and overload the `unaryPlus` method

Comment: I am trying with     `val title = object : Query("title") {}`    but it does not add the name to the query builder.

Comment: That is highly dependant on what you're doing on the rest of the code. I tried your code and it misses some methods so I updated my answer with a snippet of working code

Comment: Thanks so much it was very helpful ! 

I managed to get it to work now by creating a class `EdgeCase` which takes the parrent class as a parameter in the constructor, and then adds itself to the parrents `children` list when **initiated**. So I don't even have to use the plus operator anymore. You can see my full code on https://github.com/DAT4/gql-query-builder/blob/master/Main.kt